# Implementing multiple overloaded interfaces with `by`

Tags: kotlin

I'd like to leverage `by` to build class APIs in a nice way. Is there any way to do something like the following?

```
interface Foo<T> {

    fun foo(t: T)
}

inline fun <reified T> createFoo() = object : Foo<T> {

    override fun foo(t: T) {
        // do stuff
    }
}


// This is an error
class StringIntFoo : Foo<String> by createFoo(), Foo<Int> by createFoo()

fun main(){
    val foo = StringIntFoo()
    foo.foo("")
    foo.foo(2)
}


// Doing it manually obviously isn't an issue
class ManualStringIntFoo {

    fun foo(t: String){

    }

    fun foo(t: Int){

    }
}
```

Link to a [playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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).

It looks like the generated method end up having the same JVM signature. I was hoping the reified types would get around it. With only a single implementation it works just fine and the types look correct.

Is there some way of actually doing this? Whether or not the StringIntFoo is technically a Foo I suppose isn't important for the problem at hand. It would be cool to be able to construct classes in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it manually doesn't work either if you try to actually implement the interfaces: `ManualStringIntFoo : Foo<String>, Foo<Int>` gives the same error as `StringIntFoo`.

So `by` can't help because it still compiles to `class StringIntFoo : Foo<String>, Foo<Int>` only setting the implementation of methods.